# The King Rides. Is there a name for this?

Tags: tenses

There's a line in Mark Twain's "Yankee" that goes like this:

> "And so it might be, if he were sleeping," I said, "but the king is
>   not sleeping, the king **rides**."

The simple present here doesn't raise any flags, even though logically it should. But it doesn't. Why not? Is this a special tense of some sort, and if so, does it have a name?

Comment: Twain is writing in an affected style in that work, close to [Wardour Stree Englisht](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-war1.htm), and he is using simple present in place of present progressive ("the king **is riding**") to give it more of that archaic feel. At least the parts that contain reported speech. (Also note that he has used present progressive twice already in the same sentence. He may merely have been looking for variety.)

Comment: I would imagine that it is written that way to describe the totality of the statement. "The king is riding" implies that there is a moment in time that he is not riding. "The king rides" implies that the king *always* rides.

Comment: @TsSkTo: I doubt that very much. Do you mean to say he has no time for function of state, feasting, connubial pursuits?

Comment: @Robusto It a hyperbole to acknowledge the power that monarchs hold. So I might say that the king is not ruling, the king *rules*.

Comment: @Robusto Offhand, I'd say that "the King rides" is a shortened form of "the King pleases to ride." Stylized, yes, archaic, yes, but is there a name for it?

Comment: It would not be a shortened form of "the King pleases to ride." If it were shortened from anything of the sort, it would be "the King is pleased to ride" or "it pleases the King to ride." But you haven't yet nailed down what it is exactly that you're looking for a name to describe.

Comment: @Robusto Good point. ... Uh ... If this is a special TENSE (simple present regal, or something), does it have a name? You mentioned that Mark Twain uses it to give it "that archaic feel." Agreed. Archaic. Old. Outdated. No longer in use. Okay, WAS there a special tense, and DID it have a name (in the archaic times that Mark Twain strives to imitate here)?

Comment: What precisely is your question???

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/86/86-h/86-h.htm#c24

Comment: @Hot Licks - for the fiftieth time: Is there a NAME for this kind of tense? Present Regal? Present Declarative? Name. Term. The question is about terminology. Terminology is what the question is about.

Comment: I would say it's present tense.  I ride, you ride, he rides.  (Present perfect is what it isn't -- it's not "he is riding".  There's no law that says that present perfect must be used.)

Comment: @Hot Licks - Present Perfect would be "He has ridden." But all the concerned parties already know that he's an expert rider. So far, Present Declarative is the leading candidate.

Comment: @Ricky - Yeah, I meant "present continuous"/"present progressive".

Comment: @TsSkTo This is a different and (at least nowadays) uncommon usage of the simple present, not indicating habitual practice.

Comment: Now who's the petty spiteful bimbo who downvoted this question, one would wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monarch never does anything surprising or spontaneous.  Their activities are like the march of the seasons.  The present simple conveys this routine, distance and formality.  SO ...

*Where's Dan? He's eating.*
*Where is the king? The king eats.*

*I'm riding to London (!) and will get there by evening.

The king rides to London and will get there by evening...*

Comment: Right. So: Simple Present Regal? Simple Present Royal? Simple Present Monarchical?

Comment: I dunno!  The *monarchical present*?

Comment: When the king is riding he's just sitting there.  But when the king rides he's in control.

Comment: @Dan - Monarchical present actually works, being in keeping with, say, the royal "we." Good one!

Comment: @HotLicks  - Wow. I humbly beg your permission to put that in my play.

Comment: A 'Regal' variant on Present simple declarative seems to work, although in your example perhaps it should be, _The King rides! To London by evening._  - just to give that sense that the King's actions are declared, rather than simply being 'related in a conversational sense'.  Which also bring to mind another declarative example, "The Ambassador awaits!"

Answer (score 2):

The context of this sentence, taken from Mark Twain's 'A Connecticut Yankee in the Court of King Arthur' (http://preview.tinyurl.com/p8n2294) is that Twain's brash hero is competing with a roving charlatan to predict what King Arthur is doing, although both agree Arthur was some hundreds of miles away at that moment.  The charlatan claims that Arthur and his Court are asleep, while Twain - with the benefit of a telephone line he has laid between the cities of Arthur's Britain - announces that, "..the King rides."

One might read *'the King rides.'* as a conventional way of saying, *'the King rides out'*, or *'the King is travelling this (or that) way.'*   What is meant of course is that it is not just the King who is out for a social ride or hunt, but that he and his Court (the bodyguard and innumerable hangers-on) are on the move.  The charlatan has made an innocuous (and unprovable) prediction that the King has been asleep in his own bed for the last two hours.  The Yankee on the other hand knows exactly what the King is doing at that moment (having just got off the phone to Camelot), but needs to make a dramatic provable prediction, so declares that the King and his entire Court are 'on the road', travelling. And as the Yankee (only) knows but hasn't yet revealed, Arthur is heading 'this way'.

The Yankee is speaking in a particularly declarative way, such that charlatans (and those who compete to debunk them) and newspaper editors might use, where grammar is sacrificed on the alter of 'dramatic effect'.  One could imagine the equivalent today, as in *'Madonna Tours!'*, or *'Maradona Scores!'*, or even *'Trump stumbles!'*.

A further competition of prediction occurs where the Yankee teases out of the charlatan an estimation of the destination of the King and Court ('to the sea far north of here'), while the Yankee (having had confirmation by 'phone) is able to say 'He is coming here.' As the story relates, the Yankee's 'prediction' that Arthur is, as we might say, *'jetting over'*, is correct.  Arthur arrives a couple of days later in the town where the competition in prediction had occurred and the Yankee's reputation for knowledge of 'matters unseen' is cemented.

Comment: Good points, all. So, is there a name for it? Present Headline Special? Present Solemn? Present Regal? Present Declarative?

Comment: @Ricky.  Exactly.  I was moved to provide the context for the proper analysis, but now let the grammar gurus find a word for it.  150 bonus points to 'whomsoever satisfies this honourable quest'.

Comment: Okay. By the way: that's a pretty good synopsis of the chapter.

Comment: *Declarative* is good!

Comment: @Ricky - I wasn't meaning to patronise, honestly! (although exploring this new mode of speech is curiously empowering).  I was meaning that *declarative* sounds a better word than 'monarchical' to describe this version of the present simple.

Comment: Other examples are 'She rides!' (from 'Red Dwarf', but doubtless a cheesy quote),'Garbo Talks!' and  'Destry Rides Again'.

Comment: @Dan - I didn't think you were trying to patronize me. I took it as a compliment.